# A state-space representation of an integro-differential equation implies a false statement

Tags: dynamical-systems, laplace-transform, control-theory, inverse-laplace

I would like to convert the equation $\ddot{y}+\int_0^t y(\tau)d\tau=0$ to state-space representation. Below, I present my attempt, which seems to be contradicting, and then ask my question at the end.

**Coversion**

Let $x_1=y$ and $x_2=\dot{y}$. Also, let $x=\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right]$ and so:

$$\dot{x}=
\left[\begin{array}{c}x_2\\-\int_0^t x_1  d\tau \end{array}\right]
$$

Take Laplace transform, assuming 0 initial conditions:

$$
sX=\left[\begin{array}{c}X_2\\ -\frac{X_1}{s} \end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\-\frac{1}{s} & 0\end{array}\right]X
$$

Inverse Laplace transform:

$$
\dot{x}=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & \delta(t)\\-1 & 0\end{array}\right]x
$$

where $\delta(t)$ is the delta-dirac function (infinity at 0, and 0 elsewhere).

**Question**

The last equation implies $\dot{y}=\delta(t)\dot{y}$ and this implies $1=\delta(t)$, a false statement.

Please let me know the error in my logic.

**Comments**

(1) I know I can model the original equation using another state assignments without running into such problem of contradicting statements. For example, I can use the states $x_1=\int_0^t y(\tau)d\tau$, $x_2=y$, and $x_3=\dot{y}$. This state assignment will not result into a problem like the former one. However, this assignment results in 3-by-3 system, whereas the former results in 2-by-2 system.

(2) I also know I can differentiate the original ODE to get rid of the integral, but this will also result in a 3-by-3 system.

(3) The bottomline here: The main objective of this question is to uncover the error in my first attempt that used Laplace transform.

Comment: The problem is that the transform of a product isn't the product of the transforms

Comment: You end up with the *convolution* of $\delta$ and $x$, which is $x$. Mystery solved

Comment: @Federico I can't follow. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You wrote $sX=AX$ for some matrix $A$. Then you said that the inverse transforms brings you to $x'=Bx$ for some other matrix $B$. That is not correct. To transform a product ($AX$) you get a convolution appearing

Comment: Many thanks. Crystal clear now. So, I guess there is no way to get a closed form 2-by-2 state space representation of the original equation.

Comment: well, that i don't know. there still might be

Comment: @Federico Please answer the question. I will accept it. It is important to have the answer visible, just in case someone else runs into the same problem.

Comment: I think you need to go for the 3 dimensional system, because this is what it is. You cannot model this with a 2 dimensional state space. If you take the Laplace transform of the original equation, you also get a 3rd order transfer function.

Comment: I guess you're right @obareey . However, I thought maybe somehow you can embed the third state into the structure of the 2-by-2 A matrix, which may no longer be a constant matrix. I guess this can be done; however, is it really useful? For example, can I get the eigenvalues of the non-constant A using the conventional method, i.e.,  $\det (A-\lambda I)=0$. I guess not, right? In other words, I lost the advantages of the nice LTI state-space form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very short and sketchy answer, because I don't have enought time right now, sorry.

You wrote $sX=AX$ for some matrix $A$. Then you said that the inverse transforms brings you to $x′=Bx$ for some other matrix $B$. That is not correct. To transform a product ($AX$) you get a convolution appearing.